# How are the Elders of Xanth selected?

Tags: xanth

As the title says, how are they selected? Considering that they can have quite a bit of power, I would assume that they were people with useful and powerful talents (not necessarily at Magician class).

Comment: I thought I remembered reading that the Elders voted on new members, but I can't find that in the books.

Comment: @SaintWacko That does make sense, but what would be the criteria in order to be a nominee?

Answer (score 4):

The "Council of Elders" are fairly prominent in the series, and you would think this would be a fairly simple question.  I don't recall or find any direct mention of selection for a new member being added to "The Council of Elders".

There are a couple of hints, the most dominate being multiple mentions that the council acts on behalf of the king, when he is away.

The closest to a clear statement is this piece from "Question Quest"

> "No my time is done. since we have no magician to assume the throne, we shall simply have to make one. As King, I am the final authority on who is and is not a magician. In due course we shall have to set up a committee or council of elders for this purpose; that is one of the reforms you shall see to."

As the King is the final authority, we have clear evidence of the King forming a (special) council of elders; it follows that membership in "The Council of Elders" is at the Kings pleasure.